# What is the currently active LongListSelector Group Header

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In my Windows Phone 8 application I have use a LongListSelector control from the SDK to display hierarchical data.

How can I find out (from within my application button click handler) what the currently active (stacked on top) group header is? The SelectedItem might be null and therefore I cannot find the parent group from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a selected item you'd have to use the `ScrollOffset` of the internal `ScrollViewer` to work out how much the list had been scrolled and then determine it based on the height of the items (and headers) that have been scrolled.